# cx_Freeze:Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I downloaded cx_Freeze from [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze), installed it successfully on Ubuntu following [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304) .

After run `python3 setup.py build` in `cx_Freeze/samples/simple`,then change the dir to `cx_Freeze/samples/simple/build/exe.linux-i686-3.4`,run the following command ,I got the error

```
➜  exe.linux-i686-3.4  ./hello
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
[1]    3950 abort      ./hello
➜  exe.linux-i686-3.4
```

any idea on fixing this issue ?

Comment: The development version of cx_Freeze has another problem when using the Debian/Ubuntu system Python. You'll need to either install the latest 4.x release of cx_Freeze [from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze), or freeze applications using another Python (e.g. install [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), or compile Python yourself.)

Comment: 1) I used cx_Freeze from PyPI,then the issue was gone. 2) can we  freeze applications using Anaconda? 3) how to compile Python here?

Comment: Great, you only need to do one of the things I described. You can freeze applications using any version of Python that you can run both your application and cx_Freeze on.

Comment: This question was solved here https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/131/fatal-python-error-py_initialize-unable-to

Comment: Well, it wasn't really solved, I just wrote pretty much the same thing as in my comment here.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas K said, official cx_Freeze 5 builds have issues on Debian-based systems. If you really need to use v5, you can download my patched binaries until the issue is fixed upstream: https://github.com/peacegiverman/cx_Freeze-deb-wheels.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.x you can use 6.0b from git:

`pip install git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git`

Got rid of the error for me.